# SQLAlchemy cast to binary(N)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Am I the only one who is having this problem?

I want to write expression which will be equivalent to this sql running on MySQL:

```
select * from table1 where table1.some_column = cast('xyz' as Binary(32))
```

What I was trying in SQLAlchemy was:

```
session.Query(table1)
.filter(table1.some_column == cast('xyz', Binary(length=32))
.all()
```

However, this is incorrectly translated into:

```
select * from table1 where table1.some_column = cast('xyz' as Binary)
```

Any ideas?

I tried similar but using Numeric instead of Binary type, and it worked as expected.

Comment: My initial thought is that any column declared as `Binary(N)` is always the same as any other `Binary(n)` in MySQL when the value of `N` is between 0 and 255. For example, an integer column in MSSQL/SQLAlchemy, only needs to know max-length to know whether to use tinyint, smallint, int, or bigint. Within their respective ranges, I don't think the value matters.

Comment: If I try to execute query without length argument for binary type, I don't get any result. If I execute it with length argument for binary type, I get one row as result. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to change the SQLAlchemy source to get it to compile something differently. The relevant code for compiling `Binary` into `BINARY` is [here](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/dd4e09d38729c2479af19da082a07f0c44f7026c/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#base.py-805):

```
class MySQLCompiler(compiler.SQLCompiler):
    ...

    def visit_typeclause(self, typeclause, type_=None):
        if type_ is None:
            type_ = typeclause.type.dialect_impl(self.dialect)
        if isinstance(type_, sqltypes.TypeDecorator):
            return self.visit_typeclause(typeclause, type_.impl)
        elif isinstance(type_, sqltypes.Integer):
            if getattr(type_, 'unsigned', False):
                return 'UNSIGNED INTEGER'
            else:
                return 'SIGNED INTEGER'
        elif isinstance(type_, sqltypes.TIMESTAMP):
            return 'DATETIME'
        elif isinstance(type_, (sqltypes.DECIMAL, sqltypes.DateTime,
                                sqltypes.Date, sqltypes.Time)):
            return self.dialect.type_compiler.process(type_)
        elif isinstance(type_, sqltypes.String) \
                and not isinstance(type_, (ENUM, SET)):
            adapted = CHAR._adapt_string_for_cast(type_)
            return self.dialect.type_compiler.process(adapted)
        elif isinstance(type_, sqltypes._Binary):
            return 'BINARY'  # <-------------------------------- RIGHT HERE
        elif isinstance(type_, sqltypes.JSON):
            return "JSON"
        elif isinstance(type_, sqltypes.NUMERIC):
            return self.dialect.type_compiler.process(
                type_).replace('NUMERIC', 'DECIMAL')
        else:
            return None
```

So, we just need to intercept that with our own compilation logic:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.elements import TypeClause
from sqlalchemy.types import _Binary
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

@compiles(TypeClause, "mysql")
def _compile_typeclause(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(element.type, _Binary):
        t = "BINARY"
        if element.type.length:
            t += "({})".format(element.type.length)
        return t
    return compiler.visit_typeclause(element, **kwargs)
```